# Parsing SQL commands from a text file using regular expressions c#

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, text

I have a text file that contains sql commands divided by '/' but that also contain comments like /**/ and spaces.
I need to parse the file so I Can run every command, but I need to ignore the comments.
I've done this little code but for some reason it doesnt give me even half of the lines present in the text file:

```
public string[] Parser(string caminho)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(caminho, Encoding.Default))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = text.Split('/');
        return lines;
    }
}
```

> Is there anyway to aproach this by using a regex?
>
> Here is a link to the .txt file with the commands:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xc1ft-s78NTHdZdlpTTWlfLVE/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be higly aprecciated. Thank you

Here is an example of the file:

```
UPDATE APPLCONFIG SET GGDSC='3.5.96' WHERE GGCOD='APP_NAME'
/

UPDATE APPLCONFIG SET GGDSC='3.5.96' WHERE GGCOD='NEG_NAME'
/
UPDATE APPLCONFIG SET GGDSC='3.5.96' WHERE GGCOD='DAT_NAME'
/

ALTER TABLE PROPOSTAS ADD (COEFGERAL_PLT NUMBER(3,6) DEFAULT 0)
/

ALTER TABLE ORC
    ADD MercadoInt  VARCHAR2(1)
    ADD Coef_KrMo   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrMt   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrEq   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrSb   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_KrGb   NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_MDEmp  NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Coef_MDLoc  NUMBER(20,10)
    ADD Abrv_MDLoc  VARCHAR2(10)
    ADD Dsc_MDLoc   VARCHAR2(50)
    ADD Arred_MDLoc VARCHAR2(1)
    ADD Arred_NDecs NUMBER(1)
/
UPDATE Orc set MercadoInt='N', Coef_KrMo=1, Coef_KrMt=1, Coef_KrEq=1, Coef_KrSb=1, Coef_KrGb=1, Coef_MDEmp=1, Coef_MDLoc=1, Abrv_MDLoc='', Dsc_MDLoc='', Arred_MDLoc='N', Arred_NDecs=0 WHERE MercadoInt IS NULL
/

DROP VIEW  VW_EXPSUBEEXCELL
/
```

And another part with comments:

```
/

---------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE CDPREPORTSQL
SET COMANDOSQL_FROM =
'SELECT DESCONTO,EMPCOD,EMPDSC,LINVER,NOMESISTEMA,OBS,ORCCOD,ORCVER,PEDCOD,PEDDSC,
ROUND(PRCUNIT*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNIT,
ROUND(PRCUNITSEMDESC*#CAMBIO#,5) PRCUNITSEMDESC,
PROPCHECK,QTDGLOB,QTDPROP,REFCOD,REFDSC,EMPCODVER, COEFGERAL_PLT FROM #OWNER#.VW_PROPOSTAS', 
COMANDOSQL_WHERE = 
'WHERE ORCCOD=#ORCCOD# AND ORCVER=#ORCVER# AND NOMESISTEMA=#NOMESISTEMA# AND PEDCOD=#MYCOD#'
WHERE REPID = 'CDP0000057'
/

---------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP VIEW VW_PROPSRECEPSOUTROS
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VW_PROPSRECEPSOUTROS (orccod,
                                                              orcver,
                                                              nomesistema,
                                                              pedcod,
                                                              peddsc,
                                                              empcod,
                                                              empcodver,
                                                              empdsc,
                                                              pedtprec,
                                                              linver,
                                                              totproposta,
                                                              totdesconto,
                                                              totpropsel,
                                                              totmin
                                                             )
AS
SELECT   b.orccod, b.orcver, b.nomesistema, b.pedcod, b.peddsc, p.empcod,
            p.empcodver, h.empdsc, b.pedtprec, l.linver,
            SUM (  ((l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * (  (p.prcunit * (1 + p.deconto))) * (1 + p.coefgeral_plt)
                    * (CASE
                          WHEN r.tprec = '1'
                             THEN o.coef_krmo
                          WHEN r.tprec = '2'
                             THEN o.coef_krmt
                          WHEN r.tprec = '3'
                             THEN o.coef_kreq
                          WHEN r.tprec = '4'
                             THEN o.coef_krsb
                          ELSE 1
                       END
                      )
                   )
                ) totproposta,

            SUM( (l.qtdorc * pp.indfis * p.prcunit ) -    ((l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * (  (p.prcunit * (1 + p.deconto))) * (1 + p.coefgeral_plt)
                    * (CASE
                          WHEN r.tprec = '1'
                             THEN o.coef_krmo
                          WHEN r.tprec = '2'
                             THEN o.coef_krmt
                          WHEN r.tprec = '3'
                             THEN o.coef_kreq
                          WHEN r.tprec = '4'
                             THEN o.coef_krsb
                          ELSE 1
                       END
                      )
                   ) 
                ) * -1 as TOTDESCONTO,
           /* SUM
               (  (CASE
                      WHEN (NVL (p.deconto, 0) + NVL(p.coefgeral_plt,0)) <> 0
                         THEN (l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * ((
                                   (p.prcunit * (case when p.deconto <> 0 then p.deconto else 1 end)) * 
                                    case when p.coefgeral_plt <> 0 then p.coefgeral_plt else 0 end)
                                 * (CASE
                                       WHEN r.tprec = '1'
                                          THEN o.coef_krmo
                                       WHEN r.tprec = '2'
                                          THEN o.coef_krmt
                                       WHEN r.tprec = '3'
                                          THEN o.coef_kreq
                                       WHEN r.tprec = '4'
                                          THEN o.coef_krsb
                                       ELSE 1
                                    END
                                   )
                                )
                      ELSE 0
                   END
                  )
                * (-1)
               ) totdesconto_old,*/
            SUM
               ((CASE
                    WHEN p.empsel = 1
                       THEN   ( (l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * ((p.prcunit * (1 + p.deconto)) * (1 + p.coefgeral_plt))
                               * (CASE
                                     WHEN r.tprec = '1'
                                        THEN o.coef_krmo
                                     WHEN r.tprec = '2'
                                        THEN o.coef_krmt
                                     WHEN r.tprec = '3'
                                        THEN o.coef_kreq
                                     WHEN r.tprec = '4'
                                        THEN o.coef_krsb
                                     ELSE 1
                                  END
                                 )
                              )
                    ELSE 0
                 END
                )
               ) propsel,
              NVL (SUM (  (l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * (SELECT MIN ((pp.prcunit * (1 + pp.deconto)) * ( 1 + pp.coefgeral_plt))
                             FROM propostas pp
                            WHERE p.orccod = pp.orccod
                              AND p.orcver = pp.orcver
                              AND p.nomesistema = pp.nomesistema
                              AND p.pedcod = pp.pedcod
                              AND p.recurcod = pp.recurcod
                              AND pp.prcunit > 0
                              AND p.prcunit = 0
                              AND NVL (p.obs, '@') = '@')
                       ),
                   0
                  )
            + NVL (SUM (  (l.qtdorc * pp.indfis) * (((p.prcunit * (1 + p.deconto)) * (1+p.coefgeral_plt))
                           * (CASE
                                 WHEN r.tprec = '1'
                                    THEN o.coef_krmo
                                 WHEN r.tprec = '2'
                                    THEN o.coef_krmt
                                 WHEN r.tprec = '3'
                                    THEN o.coef_kreq
                                 WHEN r.tprec = '4'
                                    THEN o.coef_krsb
                                 ELSE 1
                              END
                             )
                          )
                       ),
                   0
                  ) totmin
       FROM pedproposta b,
            propostas p,
            empresash h,
            recursos r,
            prcficha pp,
            articlin l,
            orc o
      WHERE o.orccod = b.orccod
        AND o.orcver = b.orcver
        AND o.nomesistema = b.nomesistema
        AND b.orccod = p.orccod
        AND b.orcver = p.orcver
        AND b.nomesistema = p.nomesistema
        AND b.pedcod = p.pedcod
        AND p.empcod = h.empcod
        AND p.orccod = r.orccod
        AND p.orcver = r.orcver
        AND p.nomesistema = r.nomesistema
        AND p.recurcod = r.recurcod
        AND p.recver = r.recver
        AND p.rgmcod = r.rgmcod
        AND p.orccod = pp.orccod
        AND p.orcver = pp.orcver
        AND p.nomesistema = pp.nomesistema
        AND p.recurcod = pp.recurcod
        AND p.recver = pp.recver
        AND p.rgmcod = pp.rgmcod
        AND pp.orccod = l.orccod
        AND pp.orcver = l.orcver
        AND pp.nomesistema = l.nomesistema
        AND pp.prccod = l.prccod
        AND pp.prcver = l.prcver
        and b.pedtprec = '2'
   GROUP BY b.orccod,
            b.orcver,
            b.nomesistema,
            p.empcod,
            p.empcodver,
            h.empdsc,
            b.pedtprec,
            l.linver,
            b.pedcod,
            b.peddsc
/
```

I need to get just the commands and ignore everything else.

Comment: can you show an example of the Text File and edit your original question, you should not post a link to the file when it would have been easier to display an example of the file and it's delimiters in your original post.. also explain and or show what the unexpected output looks like. string.Split() function is very simple to use if you know what you are splitting on. you can specify multiple delimiters btw

Comment: I posted the link because the file is too large to post here and if I just post a part of it Im afraid that people wont understand what I mean. But I will edit as you suggested but I would ask you to check the link pls. the delimiter is '/' wich I used.
@MethodMan

Comment: I will not check the link because there is noway of knowing that the link is secure meaning now malicious content etc.. just post a single line showing the 2 different delimiters, simple as that!

Comment: also when do you ever issue a `COMMIT` when doing your UPDATE and or CREATE, and or DROP...?

Comment: That will be done seperatly, with the other dll functions, this dll will just parses the commands. So I dont have to worry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do a regex replace of `/* ... */` with the empty string, and then do the `Split()`. Something like

```
var foo = Regex.Replace(text, @"\/\**?\*\/", " ");
```

That'll remove the comments. When you do the split, tell it to ignore empty lines, and filter out lines that contain only whitespace:

```
var lines = foo.Split(new[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
   .ToArray();
```

Note, however, that you still have a problem if one of those queries includes the `/` character in a quoted string, for example.

You're probably better off doing this with a parser that can recognize comments, quoted strings, and other such. But the above should work well if you can live with the limitations.

Here's the full code:

```
public string[] Parser(string caminho)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(caminho);
    var foo = Regex.Replace(text, @"\/\**?\*\/", " ");
    var lines = foo.Split(new[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
       .ToArray();
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: I aprecciated the help, seems like a good idea and you pointed out some of my concerns. I think I cant use third party software but I know that MS has a namespace with a sql parser I just dont know how to use it and the examples that I find are horrible.
Im talking about Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser;

Comment: @Mr.Toxy, that code is not MSSQL Server.

Comment: @Crowcoder you're right but maybe that Parser can work with the oracle statements

Comment: @Mr.Toxy, no it won't. There is no `CREATE OR REPLACE` in MSSQL.

Comment: it exists on transact SQL wich those commands re based on

Comment: @Jim Mischel i've been checking the file and the only '/' present are the ones used to separate the commands, So I will give a try to your command, but I need a solution that works for all commands,
Is there any namespace in VS that provides methods  to treat this files?

Comment: @Jim this escape sequence isn't correct `"\/\**?\*\/", " "`
I added the verbatin sign @
`!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))` x does not exist in the current context, I cant pass "lines"...

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: See the corrected code. Replace `x` with `line`.

Comment: @JimMischel I've done that. Im not exactly understanding where to utilize that piece of code, inside a foreach to read each line from the array like this?: Should I use it inside a foreach to read each line from the array ?

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: See the updated example.

Comment: @JimMischel its working fine, I've already checked the Output but I have a concern, in the file sometimes there are lines like "------------------------------------" (without the qotes) how can I change the code in order to igonre the m?

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: add a line, `.Where(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^-+$"))`. Put that between the existing `.Where` and the `.ToArray`.

Comment: @JimMischel the code still returns the lines containing "---------------------------------------------------------------------" :\

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: That regular expression kills lines that contain nothing but dashes. If there are spaces or any other characters on the line, it's not going to eliminate them. If you want to include lines with whitespace, then replace the regex with `@"^[\s\-]+$"`

Comment: I've tried with that new regex but same result. everything else is working fine so therefore I will mark the question as accepted. but the lines still appear in the output file e.g:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP VIEW VW_PROPOSTAS`

**The line is above the command, here just appears this way**